# jQuery Navigating from text input to a page (.htm)

Tags: jquery, input, goto

This is what I'm trying to do:

I have some pages on a website (an offline demo)
When you type 'Contact' in the input field and click 'submit', I want
to go to contact.htm.

I found something similar [here](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-92278.html) (credits)

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function goTo() {
            window.location = where.value + '.htm';
            return false;
        }
    });
```

html:

```
 <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return goTo()">
    <input type="text" name="where" value="looking for"
    onfocus="if(this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = '';
    "onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = this.defaultValue;">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
 </form>
```

My question to you is; After I submit the input, this code doesn't navigate at all.

Is this the right way to do it? :  `window.location = where.value + '.htm';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML to this ->

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return goTo()">
  <input type="text" id="where" name="where" value="looking for" //added id attribute
  onfocus="if(this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = '';"
  onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = this.defaultValue;">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

and your JavaScript to this :

```
function goTo() {
    window.location = $('#where').val() + '.htm';
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

'where' doesn't mean anything.

Give your input field an id.

Then get the value by calling:-

```
$('#where').val()
```

(Assuming you give the element an id of **where**)

Comment: Ofcourse, that makes sense. How does jQuery recognize it's about a htm page?